# PageView NoSuchMethodError was thrown during performLayout()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

i'm building my first flutter application and i have this problem that i can't figure out.

The app retrieve data from a firebase realtime database, add all the entries in a list, and show all the entries in the first page of a PageView.

When i launch app in debug mode i have the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 7901): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7901): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 7901): The getter 'key' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 7901): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 7901): Tried calling: key
I/flutter ( 7901): User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 7901):   PageView-[#62d48] file:///home/amedeo/AndroidStudioProjects/pastore_app/lib/main.dart:241:17
I/flutter ( 7901): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 7901): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
I/flutter ( 7901): #1      SliverChildListDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:672:27)
I/flutter ( 7901): #2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1153:67)
I/flutter ( 7901): #3      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:137:29)
I/flutter ( 7901): #4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1153:26)
I/flutter ( 7901): #5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1166:55)
I/flutter ( 7901): #6      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2328:19)
I/flutter ( 7901): #7      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1159:11)
I/flutter ( 7901): #8      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:354:23)
I/flutter ( 7901): #9      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1797:58)
I/flutter ( 7901): #10     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:875:15)
I/flutter ( 7901): #11     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1797:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #12     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:343:5)
I/flutter ( 7901): #13     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:427:5)
I/flutter ( 7901): #14     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:196:12)
I/flutter ( 7901): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #16     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:406:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #17     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1352:12)
I/flutter ( 7901): #18     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1270:20)
I/flutter ( 7901): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #20     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #22     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #24     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #26     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #28     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #30     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #32     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #36     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #38     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter ( 7901): #39     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:444:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #40     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #41     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter ( 7901): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #43     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #45     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #46     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1232:11)
I/flutter ( 7901): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #48     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #50     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #52     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #56     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #58     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #62     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #63     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3140:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #65     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 7901): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #67     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #71     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #73     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #75     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1701:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #77     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:152:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #78     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #79     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:844:18)
I/flutter ( 7901): #80     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:341:19)
I/flutter ( 7901): #81     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:761:13)
I/flutter ( 7901): #82     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:280:5)
I/flutter ( 7901): #83     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
I/flutter ( 7901): #84     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:975:9)
I/flutter ( 7901): #85     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:784:7)
I/flutter ( 7901): #94     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter ( 7901): #95     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter ( 7901): #96     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
I/flutter ( 7901): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 7901): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderSliverFillViewport#d6420 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
I/flutter ( 7901):   creator: SliverFillViewport ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#cec9a] ← Semantics ←
I/flutter ( 7901):     _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
I/flutter ( 7901):     RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#9d04a] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
I/flutter ( 7901):     ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#04774] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 7901):   parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
I/flutter ( 7901):   constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.right, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle,
I/flutter ( 7901):     scrollOffset: 0.0, remainingPaintExtent: 600.9, crossAxisExtent: 802.7, crossAxisDirection:
I/flutter ( 7901):     AxisDirection.down, viewportMainAxisExtent: 600.9, remainingCacheExtent: 600.9 cacheOrigin: 0.0 )
I/flutter ( 7901):   geometry: null
I/flutter ( 7901):   no children current live
I/flutter ( 7901): This RenderObject has no descendants.
I/flutter ( 7901): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7901): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 7901): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
```

I have tried to add a GlobalKey to the PageView key value but it didn't work.

Maybe the problem is in the _onEntryChanged function but i commented it and the problem still remaining.
Here the code snippet:

```
 _onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    var oldEntry = carList.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.key == event.snapshot.key;
    });
    setState(() {
      carList[carList.indexOf(oldEntry)] = Car.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }
```

Here is the link of the github repo with all the file. [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/hobbit-xD/pastore_app/tree/master/lib)

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please Provide the code snippet that you think throws this error

Comment: without setting state , check what Car.fromSnapshot returns

Comment: Car.fromSnapshot returns correct value. After some changes I found out that the problem wasn't generated from that function but from the pageview inside the build. Now ISolved the problem cleaning up the code, and replacing PageView with PageView.builder. Now seems to work. This evening i will upload the correct code on github thanks for help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code isn't returning any Widget somewhere...where it should. Check that you have added 'return' where you are calling something that is to be rendered on the screen. I forgot to do it once while mapping every object of a list by calling it but not adding 'return' in front of the call. There I got the similar error log.